# C++ compilation at runtime

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-construction, runtime, shared-libraries

So I watched this video months back where Epic showcased their new Unreal Engine 4 developer features. Sorry I could not find the video but I'll try my best to explain.

The one feature that got my attention was the C++ "on the fly" modification and compilation. The guy showed how he was playing the game in editor and modified some variables in the code, saved it and the changes were immediately mirrored in game.

So I've been wondering... How does one achieve this? Currently I can think of two possible ways: either a hoax and it was only "c style"-scripting language not C++ itself OR it's shared library (read: DLL) magic.

Here's something I whipped up to try myself(simplified):

```
for(;;)
{
    Move DLL from build directory to execution directory
    Link to DLL using LoadLibrary() / dlopen() and fetch a pointer to function "foo()" from it
    for(;;)
    {
        Call the function "foo()" found in the dll
        Check the source of the dll for changes
        If it has changed, attempt to compile
        On succesfull compile, break
    }
    Unload DLL with FreeLibrary() / dlclose()
}
```

Now that seems to work but I can't help but wonder what other methods are there?
And how would this kind of approach compare versus using a scripting language?

**edit:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOvfn1p92_8&t=10m0s

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  Can you make it more specific, with a focus on the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: That's pretty cool; I wonder whether you could do something with `clang`'s JIT compilation?

Comment: C: The Complete Reference by Schildt (or was it C++?) had a sample project which was a C(++?) interpreter. Perhaps something like this, or inclusion of a miniature but actual compiler with the software.

Comment: There was a [similar thing](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/03/runtime-compiled-c-edit-and-continue-for-ms-vc-gcc-clang-llvm) recently featured on isocpp.org.

Comment: Are you sure you're not referring to [Unrealscript](http://www.unrealengine.com/en/features/unrealscript/) which looks like Java (which in turn sort of looks like C++) ?

Comment: @JesseGood, I remember playing around with that. It was pretty fun.

Comment: @fvu Epic dropped Unrealscript and it is nolonger implemented in UE4.

Comment: *"The guy showed how he ... modified some variables ... and the changes were immediately mirrored in game."*  Your debugger can do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "hot code modification" it's definitely a capability that many IDEs/debuggers can have to one extent or another.  Here's a good article:

- http://www.technochakra.com/debugging-modifying-code-at-runtime/

Here's the man page for MSVS "Edit and Continue":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Epic's Hot Reload works by having the game code compiled and loaded as a dll/.so, and this is then dynamically loaded by the engine. Runtime reloading is then simply re-compiling the library and reloading, with state stored and restored if needed.

There are alternatives. You could take a look at [Runtime Compiled C++](https://github.com/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus) (or see [RCC++ blog and videos](http://runtimecompiledcplusplus.blogspot.com/)), or perhaps try one of the other [alternatives](https://github.com/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/wiki/Alternatives) I've listed on the wiki.

As the author of Runtime Compiled C++ I think it has some advantages - it's far faster to recompile since it only compiles the code you need, and the starting point can be a single exe, so you don't need to configure a seperate project for a dll. However it does require some learning and a bit of extra code to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Neither C nor C++ require ahead-of-time compilation, although the usual target environments (operating systems, embedded systems, high-performance number crunching) often benefit greatly from AOT.

It's completely possible to have a C++ script interpreter.  As long as it adheres to the behavior in the Standard, it IS C++, and not a "hoax" as you suggest.

Replacement of a shared library is also possible, although to make it work well you'll need a mechanism for serializing all state and reloading it under the new version.

Comment: I think it would still count as a hoax if they promise performance increase by using C++ instead of a scripting language. What you suggest sounds like a scripting language in disguise.

Comment: @TheDespite: increased performance is one of the benefits of using pervasive C++ ahead-of-time-compile tools.  It's not actually a feature of the language.  Nothing in your question claimed they were promising good performance.